# sbt get build folder of RootProject

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to include in my SBT build an external project, such as:

```
lazy val leonProject = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/epfl-lara/leon.git"))
```

Now I have a custom task which needs to fetch some files of this `RootProject`.
How do I find the path to which the `RootProject` has been downloaded?

**What I have tried**

This does not exists.

```
leonProject.baseDirectory // Does not exist. There is no such field.
```

I tried looking at the documentation of sbt to see what we could do with `RootProject` and its superclass `ProjectReference` but I could not find anything (I even wrote a script to find relevant informations from their website).

I tried mimicking the behavior of the [sbt eclipse plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/), namely following [this](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbteclipse/core/Eclipse.scala) and [this](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbteclipse/core/EclipsePlugin.scala). But it only return "#footest" and never executes the inner command, event if I run `sbt footest`. It only lists the projects for which this command is activated.

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).settings(
  Keys.commands <+= ("footest")((str: String) => {
    println("#"+str)
    lazy val key = Keys.baseDirectory in ThisBuild
    def structure(state: State): BuildStructure = Project.extract(state).structure
    Command.single("footest")((state, args) => {
        println("executed")
        key.get(structure(state).data) match {
          case Some(a) => println("The project file "+a)
          case None => "Undefined setting '%s'!"
        }
        state
      }
    )
  }
))
// and call sbt foobar.
```

## My solution (thanks to @thirstycrow 's answer)

In a build.sbt file, at the top-level (for me the settings of the project did not work), write the following:

```
lazy val leonLocalBase = SettingKey[File]("leonLocalBase",  "local base for leon project")
leonLocalBase := {
  val build = loadedBuild.value
  val leonUnit = build.units(leonProject.build)
  leonUnit.localBase
}

// Now you can use leonLocalBase.value.getAbsolutePath() to retrieve the full path where leon has been downloaded.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from the loaded project structure.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {

  val leonLocalBase = SettingKey[File]("leonLocalBase", "local base for leon project")

  lazy val root = Project("root", file("."))
    .dependsOn(leonProject)
    .settings(
      leonLocalBase := {
        val build = loadedBuild.value
        val leonUnit = build.units(leonProject.build)
        leonUnit.localBase
      }
    )

  lazy val leonProject = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/epfl-lara/leon.git"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It worked for me, modulo the fact that I had to define the `leonLocalBase := { ...}` in the outer scope, not in the settings. cf. my answer